# BeautifulSoup: edit Tag.strings while iterating over Tag.strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, edit

There are many SO questions about editing the `string` or `strings` attribute of a tag, but none of the accepted answers that I could see address the problem that I am having.

If you iterate over the `Tag.strings` generator, as soon as you edit an item using `.replace_with()`, the edit is successful, but the generator immediately exits and you cannot continue iterating over the rest of the items in `Tag.strings`. The following code demonstrates this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>This <a href="../t.html">is my</a> example.</p>')
for s in soup.strings:
    s.replace_with(s.replace(' ', ''))
print(soup)
# <html><body><p>This<a href="../t.html">is my</a> example.</p></body></html>
```

What is the best way to iterate over and edit `Tag.strings` at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (inefficient) solution uses a `while` loop to check if everything that needs to be changed has been changed yet:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>This <a href="../t.html">is my</a> example.</p>')
while any(' ' in s for s in soup.strings):
    for s in soup.strings:
        s.replace_with(s.replace(' ', ''))
print(soup)
# <html><body><p>This<a href="../t.html">ismy</a>example.</p></body></html>
```

Hopefully there is a more efficient/elegant solution out there.